# Flutter (on iOS) - Asking for location permission on runtime, no dialog appearing! (Location package)

Tags: ios, flutter, location

I try to request permission for location access using Location package **on a iOS emulator**, but the dialog doesn't display?

The **try/catch block doesn't even get called**.

When I try it **on Android device, it works like a charm**.

My code:

```
try {
  if (await new Location().requestPermission()) {
    print("User granted location permission!");
    hasPermission = true;
    await checkLocationService();
  } else {
    print("User denied permission!");
  }
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
```

The package: https://pub.dev/packages/location

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to find places near to you.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to find places near to you.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to find places near to you.</string>
```

I've run 'flutter clean', no result.
I've reinstalled the app on the iOS emulator, no result.
I've even restarted iOS emulator, no result.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check to make sure the app has permissions for location in the phone settings itself.

I would personally use the permission_handler package. It handles all permissions for both android and ios with ease. I have used it on both with great success.

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-readme-tab-

Then you can use below to get the location permission which you can just put in your main function. It's also great because you can get any other permission with ease and can do it with these two lines. If the permission has been accepted it will check, confirm, and continue, if it's has not been it will ask the user for permission.

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]);
```

Comment: The dialog doesn't appear even using your suggestion. I don't know what could be causing this. I'm using iOS emulator, iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: Using permission_handler package or confirming the app itself has location permissions in the actual phone settings, or both?

Comment: Using permission_handler. It won't show the permission dialog. Only the first time user installs the app! I wanna check if user change the permission e.g. maybe to 'never', and prompt user to grant permission if so. Also, how can I check if the locaiton service is enabled? Or, can I do so with permission_handler? Maybe it's limited only to permissions..

Comment: Permission dialog is only supposed to appear the first time the user installs the app unless you press outside the dialog box therefore choosing no option, then it should prompt it again. If you choose no then you will have to change it in settings or reinstall the app. I would check out the package for more info on how to use it but you can check permissions with this below. `PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.contacts);
` So I would check the permission with this line then if permissionstatus is false request the permission.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `PERMISSION_LOCATION=1` to your `podfile`.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## Add this line
         'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1'
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

You can then request the permission using:

```dart
final status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
```